# Error 2146 in visual studio 2012 c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I was using an older version of visual studio before and now I switched to visual studio 2012 and I'm getting an error in my code. It says:

> error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'r'

How can I fix it...I've been looking for a solution for a very long time. The error is in the first line of the code...

```
template <class T1, class T2> inline void va_copy(T1& r, const T2& v) 
{
    r[0] = v[0];
    r[1] = v[1];
    r[2] = v[2];
}
```

Comment: `va_copy` is a macro from `cstdarg` header, so I guess it interprets `va_copy(T1& r, const T2& v)` as a macro invocation

Comment: better yet, use an alternative function name.

Answer (score 3):

`va_copy` is a macro defined in `stdarg.h` and that's the reason why you're getting that error. You can prevent the preprocessor from expanding the macro by adding a pair of parenthesis `()` to the function name

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdarg.h>

template <class T1, class T2> inline void (va_copy)(T1& r, const T2& v)
{
    r[0] = v[0];
    r[1] = v[1];
    r[2] = v[2];
}

int main() {
    int a[] = { 32, 33, 34 };
    const int b[] = { 22, 23, 24 };
    (va_copy)(a, b);
}
```

Comment: I recently had the same issue.